Why is Azure DevOps Services task group command interpreted as a task group variable?
The following command (point 2) $vm = az vm show --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --name $vmName --query "id" --output tsv is interpreted as a task group parameter, and automatically displayed on task group parameters (point 1).
I can't remove it as a parameter.

Why does this happen? How to prevent it?

My first impression is that you have somewhere in the script an Azure CLI command like this:
$vm = $(az vm show ...)

$(xxx) is the syntax to reference a pipeline variable. Task groups will automatically add a parameter for any string that is found between $( and ), such as $(az vm show ...):
Reproducing the issue
I just created a dummy task group with an Azure CLI task:

The following parameters were added automatically to the task group:

Workaround
Remove the $( and ) from the Azure CLI command if possible and then save the task group.

Good point, I had an $() code in the script. I forgot and I dind't expect that Task group will pick it as a parameter.
I had to replace
az vm boot-diagnostics enable --ids $(az vm show --name $vmName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query id --output tsv)
with two lines of code
$vmId = az vm show --name $vmName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query id --output tsv 
and
az vm boot-diagnostics enable --ids $vmId. Thanks!
